# How to Array Result on a Label in C# Windows Form

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms

I'm making a simple program that computes the cube of the input number. I want to array the result from 1 up to the given number but I don't how to manipulate the label control.

Here's my coding:

```
int num = 0;
int cube;
string result;

private void input()
{
    num = Convert.ToInt32(txtn­um.Text);
}

Private void btncompute_Click(obj­ect sender, EventArgs e){
    input();
    int i = 0;
    do
    {
        cube = num * num * num ;
        i++;
        result = i + " and cube of the " + i + " is :" + cube;
    } while (i < num);

    lbloutput.Text = result;
}
```

The only output here is the cube of the input number. I want to get the result from index 0 and display it on a label through array. For instance, for input 3, output should be something like this:

1 and the cube of the 1 is 1
...
3 and the cube of the 3 is 27

Your help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Please correct the formatting of your code. Only post real code! What is the question?? You could add a line break to each line; other than that, where is the problem?

Comment: `result` is already a string you can simply do `lbloutput.Text = result;`.

Comment: I see Sir. I've already changed it. Thanks Sir. @wdosanjos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things, the current logic won't give you what you want.

1. You want to multiply by i, not by num, for instance if num = 3, cube will always be 27. Based on your output you want all cubes up to and including your number.
2. You want to set i to 1 initially to start at 1, other you are starting at 0
3. You want to calculate the cube of num also, which means you have to change your loop to include num, thus i <= num

Change your code to the following:

```
int num = 0;
int cube;
string result = String.Empty;

private void input()
{
    num = Convert.ToInt32(txtn­um.Text);
}

private void btncompute_Click(obj­ect sender, EventArgs e)
{
    input();

    int i = 1;

    do
    {
        cube = i* i* i;

        result = result + String.Format("{0} and cube of the {0} is : {1}\r\n", i, cube);

        i++;
    } 
    while (i <= num);

    lbloutput.Text = result.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Hi Sir. Thanks for your response to my question. I've tried the first codes before you've edited it but it's only returning the same cubes though there's already repetition statements. Then this one does not work. I think you've replaced the variable num with i. Don't I need to declare an array variable for the cube Sir? Or something to get the value of every index of the cube?@Kweku

Comment: @curiosycar, try the new code, i have tested it and it works. Also see my comments above the code.

Comment: @curiosycar, no problem. One last thing, you don't need a do while loop here, just using a regular while statement: while(i <= num) { cube = .....} will do the trick.

Comment: @curiosycar, also if the answer works for you don't forget to click Answered, or give it a up arrow.

Comment: @Kweku , Sir I dont have enough reputation to publicly display my vote. But it says that votes with less than 15 reputation are recorded.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest part of your problem is that a label is not the appropriate control for displaying multiple lines of text.  It doesn't size or scroll based on the size of the content.  You would probably be better served with a multi-line text-box.  You can make it read-only if you don't want it editable (like a label).

In that case, you would want to call

> mytextBox.Clear()

before the loop to clear any existing text.  And then after building your result string in the loop, call

> mytextbox.AppendText(result);

to add the next iteration to the content.

Implementation left as an exercise for the reader ;)